# Set default focus on particular dropdown option that isn't first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Is there any way with css/html/js/jquery to set the focus on 'test2' for my dropdown select box, so that when the page loads the second option will be the one showing as already selected?

```
select
option test1  option
option test2  option
option test3  option 
select
```

Comment: Do you mean setting focus, or making an option initially selected? Two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Try

with **HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2" selected>test2</option>
</select>
```

---

with **js** using value

```
$(function () {
    $('select option[value="test2"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

---

with **js** using text

```
$(function () {
    $('select option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().trim() === 'test2';
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By jQuery:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Choose an item...</select>
    <option value="1">Item 1</select>
    <option value="2">Item 1</select>
    <option value="3">Item 1</select>
    ...
</select>

<script>
    $("select").val(2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

select
option test1  option
option test2  option selected
option test3  option
select

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
<select>
      <option value="test1">test1</option>
      <option value="test2" selected>test2</option>
      <option value="test3" >test3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your **HTML**:

```
<select>
      <option value="test1" selected>test1</option>
      <option value="test2" >test2</option>
      <option value="test3" >test3</option>
    </select>
```

**Javascript** for changing the selected option to test2:

```
 function Select1(){

    var ddl = document.getElementById('idSelect');

       ddl.options[2].selected = true;

    }
```

call the javascript from **body** `onload="" event`